# Panel Class, it seem to work, but nothing is showing

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

Okay i am trying to make my own PanelClass to allow stuff like double buffering etc.

And well, i am missing something, cause it´s not working, nothing is displayed. But it seems to work, as it doesn´t get stuck at the "backgroundimage = blabla".

Here is my Panel Class.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
namespace VoiceChat
{
    public class MyDisplay : Panel
    {

            public MyDisplay()
            {
                 this.DoubleBuffered = true;
                this.UpdateStyles();

            }
        }
    }
```

And then in my main form, or well the form that i am want to use it in, i do like this:

```
 private MyDisplay panelm = new MyDisplay();
```

......

```
    private void Initialize()
    {
        panelm.Size = ClientSize;
        panelm.Enabled = true;
        panelm.Visible = true;
    }
```

Just to make sure it´s visible and all that.

then  when i try to add a background image, nothing happens.

I haven´t done anything with the Paint events, as i don´t understand what to do there, and from what i understand, it doesn´t seem to be necessary.

Comment: Did you add it to the Form?  `form1.Controls.Add(panelm);`?

Comment: is it possible to make it visible in the designer mode?

Comment: Why the downvote? Granted the issue/resolution might seem obvious to most, this is a legitimate question.

Comment: Oh, didn´t notice i even got one. But well, perhaps it´s something i should have known. But i have searched everywhere, and have not seed that even once. So i guess it´s a basic of the basics.

Comment: Per your code, you added the panel dynamically.  To use the designer, you would have to select the control from the Toolbox, just like you would any other control.  Do a Rebuild first of the solution.

Comment: Hmm don´t see it there, where i put the form1.Controls.Add(panelm);, in my class, Not in the design code, if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: If you are adding it manually, it won't show up in the designer.  When you add the control through the designer, then all the information gets stored in the somewhat hidden designer file of the form.

Comment: How can i add it through the designer? Thanks

Comment: @user2587718 just place the custom panel class in your `namespace`, build your whole project then come back to the `Toolbox`, it lies at the very top of your `Toolbox`. You can also distribute your custom panel as a library (dll file), then import it to your `Toolbox` via `Right click on Toolbox -> Choose Items -> Browse to choose your dll`. After all your `custom panel` should appear in your `Toolbox` with a default icon (a circular gear).

Comment: I don´t have any dll files from my custom panel, it´s just a class in a class file;S